# Subdomains on WampServer

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, wamp

I'm working on WampServer for development, I've set up the domain tuniguide.local It works fine with this configuration:

```
DocumentRoot "D:\www\tuniguide"
```

**ServerName tuniguide.local**

But when I wanted to add a subdomain fr.tuniguide.local I get a 404 Not Found with this configuration:

```
DocumentRoot "D:\www\tuniguide\fr"
```

ServerName fr.tuniguide.local

It gives me this message: 
The requested URL /www/tuniguide/index.php was not found on this server.

Is there someting that I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to edit your host file on your server machine to have it point the correct domains to your localhost. Check out this in depth tutorial on subdomains for Wamp here: http://www.itutorblog.com/2011/06/how-to-create-a-subdomain-on-wamp/